# Escape xml characters within nodes of string xml in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, escaping

I have a string of XML data. I need to escape the values within the nodes, but not the nodes themselves.

Ex:
    `<node1>R&R</node1>`
should escape to:
    `<node1>R&amp;R</node1>`
should not escape to:
    `&lt;node1&gt;R&amp;R&lt;/node1&gt;`

I have been working on this for the last couple of days, but haven't had much success. I'm not an expert with Java, but the following are things that I have tried that will not work:

1. Parsing string xml into a document. Does not work since the data within the nodes contains invalid xml data.
2. Escaping all of the characters. Does not work since the program receiving this data will not accept it in this format.
3. Escaping all characters then parsing into document. Throws all sorts of errors.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I have a string of XML data" - no, you don't.

Comment: Correction: "I have a string of data that closely resembles XML"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use regular expression matching to find all the strings between angled brackets, and loop through/process each of those.  In this example I've used the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to do the XML escaping.

```java
public String sanitiseXml(String xml)
{
    // Match the pattern <something>text</something>
    Pattern xmlCleanerPattern = Pattern.compile("(<[^/<>]*>)([^<>]*)(</[^<>]*>)");

    StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    Matcher matcher = xmlCleanerPattern.matcher(xml);
    int lastEnd = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        // Include any non-matching text between this result and the previous result
        if (matcher.start() > lastEnd) {
            xmlStringBuilder.append(xml.substring(lastEnd, matcher.start()));
        }
        lastEnd = matcher.end();

        // Sanitise the characters inside the tags and append the sanitised version
        String cleanText = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(matcher.group(2));
        xmlStringBuilder.append(matcher.group(1)).append(cleanText).append(matcher.group(3));
    }
    // Include any leftover text after the last result
    xmlStringBuilder.append(xml.substring(lastEnd));

    return xmlStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

This looks for matches of <something>text</something>, captures the tag names and contained text, sanitises the contained text, and then puts it back together.

Comment: I went with something very similar to this. It seems to work fine, but I'm a little worried about a couple of niche cases. I'm planning on going through and making a few changes to my code based on your suggestion.

Comment: One thing to note; This suggestion works great if your XML doesn't contain child nodes. However it will need to be modified if you have data in this form:
    `<ParentNode>  
         <childNode1>data</childNode1>  
         <childNode2>da&&ta</childNode2>  
      </ParentNode>`

This will return only the child nodes and the parent node will be lost.

Comment: No, any non-matching text between the matches will also be included  in the result, so child nodes should work fine.  One thing that it doesn't try to fix is illegal characters inside quoted attribute strings, e.g. <node name="Some & value" />

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `<node1>R&R</node1>` is not XML.

- Using XML parsers will not help. The purpose of an XML parser is to filter out this kind of data.
- You can try a [different parser](http://jsoup.org/) that was made to parse "dirty" HTML.

But I think the best solution would be to get correct XML in the first place:

- Fix the XML source by using an XML lib to create the data. (And never do String concatenation to create XML)
- If the data is provided for you, create an XML-Schema and insist on validity of your input data.

Comment: This wont work since I'm working with a fixed length set of data. For example: I get 100 bytes of data and it happens to contain an ampersand. It then goes through the process of parsing these 100 bytes into an XML schema that is expecting exactly 100 bytes. If I escape the XML characters before parsing, I am now sending 104 bytes through the schema, and all of the data is incorrectly shifted.

Answer (score 0):

What you've presented isn't XML. It's XPL. XPL is structured just like XML but allows XML's "special characters" in text fields. You can easily do the XPL to XML conversions with the XPL utilities. http://hll.nu

Answer (score -1):

I've used Nameless Voices answer but with a regex of:

```
Pattern xmlCleanerPattern = Pattern.compile("(<[^<>]*>)(.*)(<\\/[^<>]*>)")
```

I find this captures all the values within the nodes themselves a bit better