# Escape XML Characters for Attribute values Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, escaping

I have an XML represented in String. I need to replace all the special characters in the Attribute values with the Escape Characters.
For Ex:
I want to convert 1st one to the second one as following.

```
<r1 c1=\"01\" c168=\"<A_ATTR><Updates A_VALUE="959" /><Current A_VALUE="100" /></A_ATTR>\"/> 

<r1 c1=\"01\" c168=\"&lt;A_ATTR&gt;&lt;Updates A_VALUE=&quot;959&quot; /&gt;&lt;Current A_VALUE=&quot;100&quot; /&gt;&lt;/A_ATTR&gt;\"/>
```

This questions is similar to the below one : But I need to escape the attribute values. Please advise.
[Escape xml characters within nodes of string xml in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825261/escape-xml-characters-within-nodes-of-string-xml-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use string replace function to replace the required character by the encoding. Example below

if your xml string is s then

```
s = s.replace("<", "&lt;");
s = s.replace(">", "&gt;");
```

Comment: To replace them with Escape Characters, I'm using StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML(String). My challenge it to go over each attribute in the xml. Regex seems complicated.So looking for any other alternatives.

Comment: Are you parsing XML ? which parser you are using ?